# Búsquedas en rango de fechas whereBetween()

Tags: laravel

Tengo un pequeño buscador y deseo agregarle la opción de filtrar en un rango de fechas que el usuario elija, lo estoy haciendo la la siguiente manera pero no funciona, ni siquiera buscar por el campo (Nombre) que funcionaba anteriormente (Creo que es porque el between debería ser opcional), probé con unos condicionales en el controlador para ver si funcionaba la busqueda del campo nombre pero tampoco funcionó.

Tengo lo siguiente en el controlador:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $start = new DateTime($request->start);
    $end = new DateTime($request->end);

    $visits =  Visit::leftjoin('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->selectRaw('visits.id as vid, users.name as uname, visits.first_name as vfn, visits.last_name as vln, visits.cuit as vc, DATE_FORMAT(visits.created_at, "%d-%m-%Y") as date, TIME(visits.created_at) as hour')
            ->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$start, $end])
            ->search($request->visits)
            ->paginate(12);

    return view('admin.dashboard.visits.admin-index', compact('visits'));

}
```

Y en mi Modelo (Scope):

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(visits.first_name, ' ', visits.last_name, ' ', visits.cuit, users.name)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(visits.first_name, ' ', visits.last_name, ' ', visits.cuit, users.name)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Cuando el usuario no coloca las fechas debería buscar por el criterio que escribió en el input text

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112238/discussion-on-question-by-joseph-busquedas-en-rango-de-fechas-wherebetween).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví quitando el `whereBetween()` del controlador y lo coloqué en el `scope`

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
  if ($find->start == NULL)
  {
    $find->start = "2020-01-01";
    $dateStart = new DateTime($find->start);
  }
  else
  {
    $dateStart = new DateTime($find->start);
  }
  
  if ($find->end == NULL)
  {
    $find->end = "2021-12-31";
    $dateEnd = new DateTime($find->end);
  }
  else
  {
    $dateEnd = new DateTime($find->end);
  }

    $search = explode(" ", $find->visits);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(visits.first_name, ' ', visits.last_name, ' ', visits.cuit, users.name)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%")->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$dateStart->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"]);
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(visits.first_name, ' ', visits.last_name, ' ', visits.cuit, users.name)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%")->whereBetween('visits.created_at', [$dateStart->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"]);
          }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Que bueno publicaste tu solución, +1

Comment: No lo hice antes porque estaba ocupado. Gracias por tu ayuda!